# How can I fetch request URI in ingress configuration-snippet?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I want to read the request URI(excluding hostname and request params) and forward it in a custom header to an upstream server. I have been through several blogs where they have mentioned to use $request_uri but its not working.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    proxy_set_header RequestURI $request_uri
```

May I know which language is used to write scripts in annotation snippets? And is there is any list of variables which are by-default provided by ingress controller that we can use inside annotations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> which language is used to write scripts in annotation snippets?

There are no special language, the format is the Nginx configuration format.

Everything you put there will be added to a [location](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html?&_ga=2.121880715.180798959.1590354221-351902990.1590354221#location) section related to your Ingress route in an Nginx configuration generated by Ingress controller.

> is there is any list of variables which are by-default provided by ingress controller that we can use inside annotations?

[Here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) is a list of embedded Nginx variables.

Comment: Anton, thanks for your help.  I tried writing bash linux scripts in configurtion-snippet block and it failed. How can I learn writing Nginx configurations in its format? Is there any reference doc for this?

Comment: I recommend you to google around "nginx configuration file example" and read docs [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/).

Comment: Thank you Anton.